# Is it possible to stub or mock a SocketChannel with Spock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock, socketchannel

Essentially I have a Java class which performs a select on a socket channel, and I want to stub the channel such that I can test select works as expected.

For example, this is roughly what the class being tested does:

```
class TestedClass {
    TestedClass(SocketChannel socket) { this.socket = socket }

    // ...
    SocketChannel socket;
    // ...
    void foo() {
        // Wait a while for far end to close as it will report an error 
        // if we do it.  But don't wait forever! 
        // A -1 read means the socket was closed by the other end.
        // If we select on a read, we can check that, or time out 
        // after a reasonable delay.

        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        socket.configureBlocking(false);
        socket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        while(selector.select(1000) == 0) {
            Log.debug("waiting for far end to close socket...")
        }

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
        if (socket.read(buffer) >= 0) {
            Log.debug("far end didn't close");
            // The far end didn't close the connection, as we hoped
            abort(AbortCause.ServerClosed);
        }

        Log.debug("far end closed");
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to test something like this:

```
def "test we don't shut prematurely" () {
    when:
    boolean wasClosedPrematurely
    SocketChannel socket = Stub(@SocketChannel) {
        // insert stub methods here ....
    }

    TestedClass tc = new TestedClass(socket)
    tc.foo();

    then:
    wasClosedPrematurely == false
}
```

This based on a real example, but the details aren't important.  The general aim is how to stub SocketChannels which support selects, so that I don't have to create a real client to test against.

I also know it's more complicated than just stubbing SocketChannel: it seems like I need to intercept `Selector.open()` or somehow provide a custom system default SelectorProvider.  If I simply stub SocketChannel I get an IllegalSelectorException when I try to register the selector obtained via `Selection.open()` with my stub, and the base `AbstractSelectableChannel#register` method is unfortunately final.

But I cannot find any useful pointers on how or whether this is even possible with Spock Mocks, and it seems like it might be quite a common thing to want, so a good question to ask here.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Spock uses [CGLIB](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) to mock/stub/spy classes. CGLIB cannot override final methods. SocketChannel has a lot of final methods (e.g. configureBlocking), however, CGLIB doesn't fail but uses original methods. As configureBlocking is final it is used in your test.

`public final SelectableChannel configureBlocking(boolean block)
        throws IOException 
    {
        synchronized (regLock) {
            if (!isOpen())
                throw new ClosedChannelException();
            if (blocking == block)
                return this;
            if (block && haveValidKeys())
                throw new IllegalBlockingModeException();
            implConfigureBlocking(block);
            blocking = block;
        }
        return this;
    }`

So configureBlocking requires having the regLock variable initialized, but as you make stub for this class the variable is not initialized and you get NPE here.

The question is what to do with it?
Well, I'd say, first of all, try to use interfaces but not classes. 
If it's not possible try not to invoke final methods. 
If it's still impossible you have to look inside the class and figure out what should be mocked. 
The last option I see is to make a full integration test: creaeting two sockets and connecting them.

Comment: Stubbing SocketChannel with a wildcard method `_ >> { new Exception().printStackTrace() }` shows both configureBlocking and implConfigureBlocking being called; for some reason adding a stub method for the latter doesn't work for me.  But this isn't the show-stopper - it's when the #register method is called.  That is also final, and something internal (Java 7) checks that the socket provider implements an internal private interface, and throws IllegalSelectorException if not,

Comment: I think the problem is in SelectorImpl::register, line #117.
   if(!(var1 instanceof SelChImpl)) { 
            throw new IllegalSelectorException();
        } else { ...
Frankly, you can't have an instance of abstract class (SocketChannel), but CGLIB lets you have one. Try to use SocketChannelImpl instead of SocketChannel as a dirty hack, but I'd review the whole test, think of its type (unit, acceptance, integration), what it does and rewrite it without using of hacks and tricks like stubbing abstract classes.

Comment: Precisely: either I have to use the whole internal implementation in order to get a SelChImpl instance, or I have to somehow induce `Selection.open()` to return one of my own, which doesn't impose this check.  I was hoping there might be some prior art out there for the latter solution, since it seems to require re-implementing a bunch of interconnected types.  Either way, NIO's design seems to thwart easy unit testing! And there is very little comment on that on the web.

Comment: I would ask you what you want to test indeed?

Comment: Well, initially I just wanted to maintain some tests for code refactored from old-IO to NIO.  Socket / Stream are relatively straightforward to stub, and so they were.   These tests were for a subsystem, rather than a single class, and so weren't strict single-class unit tests, but they aimed to test server-side error cases which were not so easy to directly control or access through a stub client using a real socket, such as time-outs, and specific return codes from the socket.  You might consider them regression tests.

Comment: ...But more generally, I also want to know if SocketChannel is intractable for testing like this (which I'd consider a JRE design failure).

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have discovered an answer to my own question.

So `Selector.open()` can't directly be intercepted - but it simply calls `SocketProvider.provider().openSelector()`, and `SocketProvider.provider()` is a lazy static accessor for the `SocketProvider.provider` field.  (At least in my case, Java 7)

Therefore, we can simply set this `provider` field, even though it is private, because Groovy can ignore normal Java visibility restrictions.  Once set to our own stub instance, all future `Selector.open()` calls will use it henceforth (with the obvious caveat that this is a global change which could affect other code not under test).

The details depend on what you want to do then, but as below you can return stubs of the other classes such as AbstractSelectableChannel.

Working example follows.

```
class SocketStubSpec extends Specification {

    SocketChannel makeSocketChannel(List events) {
        // Insert our stub SelectorProvider which stubs everything else
        // required, and records what happened in the events list.
        SelectorProvider.provider = Stub(SelectorProvider) {
            openSelector() >> {
                Map<SelectionKey, AbstractSelectableChannel> keys = [:]

                return Stub(AbstractSelector) {
                    register(_,_,_) >> { AbstractSelectableChannel c, int ops, Object att ->
                        events << "register($c, $ops, $att)"
                        SelectionKey key = Stub(SelectionKey) {
                            readyOps() >> { events << "readyOps()"; ops }
                            _ >> { throw new Exception() }
                        }
                        keys[key] = c
                        return key
                    }
                    select() >> {
                        events << "select()"
                        return keys.size()
                    }
                    selectedKeys() >> { keys.keySet() }
                    _ >> { throw new Exception() }
                }
            }
            _ >> { throw new Exception() }
        }

        return Stub(SocketChannel) {
            implConfigureBlocking(_ as Boolean) >> {  boolean state -> events << "implConfigureBlocking($state)" }
            _ >> { throw new Exception() }
        }
    }

    def "example of SocketChannel stub with Selector" () {
        given:
        List events = []

        // Create a stub socket
        SocketChannel channel = makeSocketChannel(events)

        Selector selector = Selector.open()
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        SelectionKey key = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

        expect:
        selector.select() == 1 // our implementation doesn't block
        List keys = selector.selectedKeys().asList()

        keys == [key] // we have the right key
        key.isReadable() // key is readable, etc.

        // Things happened in the right order
        events == [
            "implConfigureBlocking(false)",
            "register(Mock for type 'SocketChannel', 1, null)",
            "select()",
            "readyOps()",
        ]
    }
}
```